# Implement ADFS without using MVC pattern?

Tags: active-directory, adfs, ws-federation

Currently the project that I'm working with is developing using ASP.NET Web Forms, I hardly find any example online that ADFS could be integrated with ASP.NET Web Forms, all of them are ADFS with MVC such as http://www.dotnetcurry.com/windows-azure/1166/aspnet-mvc-multiple-adfs-owin-katana.

Ask if it possible that the ADFS can be implemented using ASP.NET Web Forms without using MVC? And if so which helpful article can I refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Use WIF as the means of getting to ADFS. This essentially just uses changes to the web.config. If you have an old VS e.g. 2012 / 2012, you can use the "Add STS" or the "Identity and Access Tool" to hook everything up for you.

Good overview [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/security/how-to-build-claims-aware-aspnet-web-forms-app-using-wif).

Comment: to implement multiple ADFS does WIF still apply to cater this situation?

Comment: You need to define "multiple ADFS". What's your use case?

Comment: e.g. web forms application need to be integrated with ADFS from Antariksh.com and IndiaUniverse.com, in short multiple ADFS integration in single ASP.NET Web Forms application.

Comment: Out of the box, you can't do that. The web.config points to one ADFS only, What you can do is run up your own ADFS. Connect your app to that. Federate that with as many other ADFS as you want.

Comment: Or use IDaaS e,g, Okta, Auth0. Connect your app to that. Federate that with as many other ADFS as you want.